# Problems with Black Box KVM

Tags: kvm-switch

I just recieved a shipment of equipment orderd by my predicessor that includes brand new Dell Optiplex 990 computers, with standard mice and keyboards.  Also included were Black Box ServSwitch Secure KVMs.

I've worked with KVMs before and hypothetically they should be the easiest thing in the world to deal with, plug it all together, push the button, go.

However, for the life of me I can't get the computers to recognize the mouse or keyboard when plugged into the KVM.  We've seen this with multiple KVMs across the order.

Any one know what I'm missing?

Computers are all Dell 990 with Windows 7.

Comment: Are you using the right cables for the switch? I know that some of the Black Box switches require special cables.

Comment: We are using Black Box brand cables, which are also brand new.